# Silent Renew with Identity Server 4 and Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have an identity server 4 web application that uses asp.net core identity and azure ad to authenticate users.  The problem I'm encountering is that silent renew doesn't work for azure ad users.  It works fine if you login with the user name and password of an identity user.

If you login using an Azure AD user when the client application triggers a silent renew I see the following error in the identity server logging:

> Showing error: prompt=none was requested but user is not authenticated

For the handling of the external auth I'm using the external controller which can be found at the quickstart here:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs

I also pulled some sample code and the Microsoft.Identity.Web project from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2.

At this point I've tried a dozen different things.  The below is from my startup class in it's current state.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/"; // Microsoft identity platform

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";

                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("openid");

                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    var login = context.Properties.GetParameter<string>(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.LoginHint);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(login))
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = login;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = context.Properties.GetParameter<string>(
                            OpenIdConnectParameterNames.DomainHint);

                        // delete the login_hint and domainHint from the Properties when we are done otherwise
                        // it will take up extra space in the cookie.
                        context.Properties.Parameters.Remove(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.LoginHint);
                        context.Properties.Parameters.Remove(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.DomainHint);
                    }

                    // Additional claims
                    if (context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("claims"))
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("claims",
                            context.Properties.Items["claims"]);
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };

                var handler = options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
                options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                {
                    var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
                    await tokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(context, options.Scope).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await handler(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
                };

                // Handling the sign-out: removing the account from MSAL.NET cache
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    // Remove the account from MSAL.NET token cache
                    var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
                    await tokenAcquisition.RemoveAccountAsync(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
                };
            })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Any advice, suggestions, or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error, but this time try and go to some Microsoft website requiring authentication and see if you still have the authentication cookie they administer.